# Calculating discount on final amount

Tags: python-3.x

I have written the following code

```
total=0
n=int(input('enter number of items: '))
for i in range(n):
    cost=int(input('Please enter a item cost:'))
    total+=cost
    if total>=1000:
        print('Discount of 10%')
        total*=0.9
        print('final total is',total)
    elif total<1000:
        print('Discount of 5%')
        total*=0.95
        print('final total is',total)
```

I wanted to calculate discount only on the final amount but not on each product. How can I modify my code?

Comment: You just need to take if-elif statements outside of for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your `if-elif` outside the for loop, which in Python just means to un-indenting it. The `for` loop will then just calculate total, and then after it is done, the conditional is evaluated.